# Network socket icon not showing up in tray (lubuntu 18.04)

Tags: lubuntu, icons, openvpn, lxde, system-tray

I've added the OpenVPN configuration in **lubuntu** 18.04 32 bit. But the network socket icon is not showing up in the tray anymore. So I'm unable to use OpenVPN from GUI. Images from some online tutorials below show the icon I'm talking about. Even though the images are from **Lxqt**, my **Lxde** based desktop is not showing the icon to enable/disable network and OpenVPN connections. Can someone please suggest how to fix this? Thanks.

[image: example 1]

[image: example 2]

Image courtesy: [PureVPN](https://support.purevpn.com/how-to-setup-vpn-on-lubuntu), [IPVanish](https://support.ipvanish.com/hc/en-us/articles/360004497234-OpenVPN-setup-in-Lubuntu-)

Comment: 19.10 is EOL and off-topic.

Comment: If you're using Lubuntu 18.04 32-bit as you say, why does your picture show a LXQt environment & wallpaper from a now EOL release?  I see no LXDE pictures only `lxqt-panel`

Comment: If you are using a LXQt based Lubuntu in 32-bit (i386), you should either re-install an amd64/64-bit supported Lubuntu, or if your hardware is only x86/i386, return to Lubuntu 18.04 LTS and LXDE via re-install. Lubuntu provided packages for i386 until the end of the 19.04 cycle, and whilst it was possible to force upgrade to 19.10 during alpha & early beta development cycle, the build processes were turned off, and binaries removed late in the beta cycle meaning your system should not be used online...

Comment: Hi guiverc, I added the pictures from PureVPN and IPVanish tutorials. The network socket icon is not visible on my system. I have a fresh install of Lubuntu 18.04.5 LTS 32 bit desktop image from the following URL. My system is core 2 duo with 2 GB RAM. https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/18.04/release/

Comment: The pictures you added do not relate to your machine at all. The pictures are from modern Lubuntu running LXQt. Your system is legacy Lubuntu so it will be different (any panel items for `lxqt-panel` won't help your system as you have no `lxqt-panel`, instead your system uses `lxpanel` which it may not cater for.  Did you adjust your installation to match a LXDE setup instead of a LXQt/Qt5 setup?  Details of instructions you followed may help, as you've just raised more questions that it has helped (*you're expecting a setup for one system that does not match you you're using*)

Comment: FYI:  I tested & regularly use c2d boxes (though usually with more RAM), the box I'm replying on runs a c2q-9400 (running *hirsute* or what will become 21.04) being only slightly upmarket to c2d. Your system will run modern Lubuntu, in fact I use a "lenovo thinkpad sl510 (c2d-t6570, 2gb ram, i915)" in testing which has only 2GB of ram.  If you plan on using your system past April-2021 I'd consider a modern Lubuntu using LXQt

Comment: Okay, I didn't know about the lxde - lxqt versions in Lubuntu. Maybe I should remove the images. Though the question remains regarding how to enable/disable wifi and openvpn connections. The icon to do that is not showing up.

Comment: On a different note, you mean to say that my system will be able to handle Lubuntu 20.04.1 LTS 64 bit properly?

Comment: I don't have many details of your system, but I tested Lubuntu on many c2d systems (t6570,  6600, e6850, e8300 etc) and actually used 1GB systems to test up to the 19.04 cycle so I'm betting yes. There are minor costs with only 2GB of RAM (x86_64 is slightly less efficient in RAM use as 64bits are used for  non-local addresses (twice as much as 32bits), but your cpu actually runs faster so difference is minimal; let alone modern Lubuntu has an upgrade path). I'm likely unable to respond any more (my Ubuntu SSO doesn't include chat as that's on SE/Stack Exchange where I'm not logged in).